# Can you say "paint price" instead of "painting price"?

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives, syntactic-analysis, attributive-nouns

Is this sentence ok as currently written?

> The **paint price** is high.

I ask because the [free online proofreading service from Grammarly, Inc.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammarly) tries to change that sentence to *The **painting** price is high*, but the purpose of the sentence is to denote that the price of the paint is high, not the price of the painting process.

Is this just some dumb software bug, or am I missing something important here?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it, if you are, say, reviewing a list of costs for some project.

Comment: "Paint" is a synecdoche. It is a substitute noun that has been merged into a compound noun. If the "paint" is a job lot of various colors, finishes, and quantities, the paint price is the total cost of all of it, and there isn't a better way to say that.

Comment: 'The price of the paint is high' is what real people would say. Or 'The paint is expensive'.

Comment: For gods' sake, why is anyone paying attention to Grammarly? It's crap.

Comment: @JohnLawler do you have an alternative to suggests which corrects grammar on an internet browser?

Comment: No. Probably you could do better with translation software; your browser will not correct your grammar to make it look like a native speaker's.

Comment: Grammarly is not very smart and doesn't understand your meaning. Like autocorrect, it tries to make you change to something that is commonly written even if it is wrong.

Comment: @JohnLawler so you could tell that I was not a native speaker?

Comment: No, but I could guess. For one thing, the vast majority of questions here come from non-native speakers, who often feel like they should keep it a secret, it seems, though it becomes obvious in the first sentence in speech. Also, native speakers rarely ask questions like that.

Comment: @JohnLawler 
> "who often feel like they should keep it a secret,"
We do that because we are not taken seriously by native speakers once they realize we're not "native".

Comment: That's what you think. But if you're asking questions about English, it makes a **BIG** difference whether you have a native speaker's intuition (plus the usual clueless anxiety formed by Anglophone education), or intuition about other languages (which ones makes another big difference) plus a slew of correct and ridiculous "grammar rules" delivered in a slew of correct and ridiculous schools. As I said, native speakers ask different questions and need different answers.

Answer (score 2):

If you check [Gngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+paint+price%2Cthe+price+of+the+paint%2C+paint+prices&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20price%20of%20the%20paint%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpaint%20prices%3B%2Cc0) you will find that the phrase ***the paint price*** is simply not used. I have, however, found that

> the price of the paint (the price of paint - also possible)

or

> paint price***s*** (less common)

are used instead.

The only instance I could find of "paint price" was in this ad from Google:

[image]

Comment: The same applies whatever the commodity; _the price of food_ or _food prices_. Not so much a question of grammar as idiomatic usage.

Comment: *Paint price* is fine. It could be used idiomatically in something like the following: On this job, there’s a lot of detail and not much surface area, so your *paint price* won’t be the big issue. It’s mostly labor, plus a prep charge if you want light over dark.